# Combobox2 list depends on the choice of combobox1

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have 2 combobox are in a `userform1`

possible rowsource:
sheet1 for food lets say all is in row A 
Sheet2 for drinks

Combobox1 has 2 choices e.g. "food", "drinks"
IF "food" is selected then rowsource from sheet1 will auto populate 
IF "drinks" is selected then rowsource from sheet2 will auto populate

I'm not really sure on how to do this.
I don't even have a sample code or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in `ComboBox1_Change` event:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

        Dim Dsh As String, Fsh As String, Sh As Worksheet, Lr As Long
        Fsh = "Sheet1"
        Dsh = "Sheet2"

        Select Case Me.ComboBox1.Value
         Case "food"
           Set Sh = Sheets(Fsh)
         Case "drinks"
           Set Sh = Sheets(Dsh)
         Case Else
          Exit Sub
        End Select

        Lr = Sh.Range("A" & Sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.ComboBox2.List = Sh.Range("A1:A" & Lr).Value

    End Sub
```